# Setting a timeout during a loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, timeout, subprocess

So I'm running a loop through a directory where an external script, run by subprocess.Popen, is moving through the directory and performing calculations on each file.  The external script is a bit unstable and occasionally freezes when it runs into files that it doesn't know how to handle.  Is there a way to add a timeout function to subprocess.Popen so that I can skip over that file and move on to the next?

EDIT:
Here's my loop:

```
def automate():
    os.chdir("/home/mlts/dir")
    working_dir = b"/home/mts/dir"
    for filename in os.listdir(working_dir):
        if filename.endswith(".MTS"):
            try:
                print("Performing calculations on {filename!r}...".format(**vars()))
                try:
                    os.remove("mts_tbl.txt")
                except OSError:
                    pass
                time.sleep(3)
                p = Popen(["run_command.command", "-f", "a"], cwd=working_dir, stdin=PIPE)
                p.communicate(input=b"\n".join([b"1", str(filename), b"8", b"alloy-liquid", b"0", b"x", b"5", b"4", b"-1.6", b"4", b"1", b"0"]))
```

Comment: One can help you over timeout part as is but for skip over the file script freezes on, you must provide code

Comment: Got it.  Edit provided...

Comment: You are missing the final " on the os.chdir line

Comment: To do 2 things at once, 1=run the function, 2=cancel after a certain amount of time has passed, you use Multiprocessing or Threading.  Personally, I would call the function as a multiprocessing process, and terminate the process after the allowed time has passed.  Doug Hellmann's page is at https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html#terminating-processes

Comment: Would this approach allow for the continuation of the loop onto the next file in the directory?

Comment: unrelated: don't call `str(filename)`; it is pointless on Python 2 (it is already has `str` type there) and it fails on Python 3; pass `filename` as is as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33170992/4279)

Comment: pass `timeout` parameter to `.communicate()`, see [subprocess with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12698328/4279)

Comment: is it intentional that `os.chdir()` argument differs from `working_dir`?

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding in general and I probably have a lot of redundant lines.  Only thing that matters to me right now is that it works (and it does, minus the timeout issue).  I'll clean it up later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force `timeout` on Python 2 (where `.communicate(timeout=)` doesn't exist in stdlib), you could use [`threading.Timer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects):

```
p = Popen(...)
t = Timer(3, p.kill) # kill in 3 seconds
t.start()
p.communicate(...)
t.cancel() # no need to kill, the process is dead already
```

The complete example:

```
import os
import traceback
from glob import glob
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Timer

os.chdir("/home/mls/dir") #XXX assume mlts is a typo in the question
for filename in glob(b"*.MTS"):
    print("Performing calculations on {filename!r}...".format(**vars()))
    try:
        os.remove("mts_tbl.txt")
    except OSError:
        pass # ignore
    try:
        p = Popen(["run_command.command", "-f", "a"], stdin=PIPE) #XXX no cwd
        t = Timer(3, p.kill)
        t.start()
        p.communicate(input=b"\n".join([b"1", filename,
                b"8\nalloy-liquid\n0\nx\n5\n4\n-1.6\n4\n1\n0"]))
        t.cancel()
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

This code assumes that you want to run the child process in the current working directory of the parent Python script.

On Python 3 or if `subprocess32` is installed; you could pass `timeout` parameter to `.communicate()` method instead of using `Timer()`.